# Recycler View Data is not getting Updating?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-viewholder

I Have a recycler view in a Fragment it has the list of buttons .When a user presses the button it opens another activity to edit name and other data .when its returning back to the fragment it is not able to update the name of the text view and also when i am deleting the item it is showing the old name whenever i save a new item in the list .Please help me out with it.

```
public void updateScreen(String name, int pos) {
        modelList.add(new DataModel(name, R.drawable.custom_mode));
        mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(pos);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void deleteDataUi(int pos) {
        Log.e("DelteUIpos:", String.valueOf(pos));
        modelList.remove(pos);
        mrecycler.removeViewAt(pos);
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(pos);
        mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, dataList.size());
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void updateNameUI(int pos, String nm) {
        dataList.get(pos).setImageName(nm);
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(pos);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

2nd Activity

```
        case R.id.saveMode:
            MainFragm fragMain = new MainFragm ();
                    fragMain .updateScreen(edname, position);
                    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(secondActivity.this);
                    finish();
               break;
        case R.id.EditMode:
            MainFragm fragMain = new MainFragm ();
           fragMain.updateNameUI(position,edname.getText().toString());
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(secondActivity.this);
                finish();
            break;
        case R.id.deleteMode:
            MainFragm fragMain = new MainFragm ();
            fragMain.deleteDataUi(Dataposition);
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(secondActivity.this);
            finish();
            break;
```

Adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter .Holder> {
    private ArrayList<DataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    CustomAdapter (Context context, List<DataModel> dataModelsList) {
        mContext = context;
        dataModels = (ArrayList<DataModel>) dataModelsList;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //Inflate the layout, initialize the View Holder
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        return new CustomAdapter.ViewHolder(v);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        //Use the provided View Holder on the onCreateViewHolder method to populate the current row on the RecyclerView
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(dataModels .get(position).getImg());
        holder.textView.setText(dataModels .get(position).getTextName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //returns the number of elements the RecyclerView will display
        return dataModels.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }


    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageButton imageView;
        TextView textView;

        ViewHolder (View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_view);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit_tv);
            int width = 250;
            int height = 250;
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a public getter for `dataModelsList` in `CustomAdapter` which returns reference dataset.

then instead using `modelList.remove(pos);`

use this:

`mAdapter.createdGetterMethod().remove(pos)`

and

instead using 
`dataList.get(pos).setImageName(nm);` use this:

`mAdapter.createdGetterMethod().get(pos).setImageName(nm);`

Comment: Remove item worked flawlessly .How to edit the name and update in ui  ?